# How to get all options for com.apple.finder.plist in ~/Library/Preferences?

Tags: finder, macos

How people know what's possible to be changed via CLI in OSX / macOS if `com.apple.finder.plist` is a binary file and calling `cat` command for that file  shows only a binary gibberish output?

```
cat ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
```

I've found great option in macOS Sierra:

> Keep folders on top when sorting by name

What's the name of it's `defaults write` so that I can add it into my [settings script](https://github.com/mattkomarnicki/shell-scripts/blob/master/macOS/adjust.sh)?

Basically instead of guessing I would like to know where to find all possible options. Does Apple provide it somewhere? I know [this site](http://www.defaults-write.com/) but it's not up to date...

[image]

Comment: idk what the cat command does, but com.apple.finder.plist is a plaintext xml file; ought to be relatively simple to find that command by toggling the pref. Not on Sierra to be able to test.

Comment: @Tetsujin, The preference file for Finder, as stored on disk, is in fact a binary plist file not an xml file. It's just being displayed as such in the preview in Finder and or an app like TextWrangler.

Comment: ah, OK. Then it would make more sense to view it from TextWrangler... which is what I usually do ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To read/write *.plist* files, use the `defaults` command.

The *key* that gets set when checking the **[√] Keep folders on top when sorting by name** check box under **Advanced** in **Finder Preferences** is named: `_FXSortFoldersFirst`

To set this in Terminal (or script) use the following *command*:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXSortFoldersFirst -bool YES
```

To unset, use the following *command*:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXSortFoldersFirst -bool NO
```

Note that in previous OS versions, **Finder** needed to be restarted using `killall Finder` to have some settings, when changed by `defaults`, work properly. In **macOS 10.12**, this is not necessary for this particular setting, however the **Finder** window does need to be refreshed by some means, e.g. toggling from list view to icon view and back.

---

If you want to toggle between List view and Icon view in the *bash script* vs. using `killall Finder` after using `defaults write ...`, use the following *code* block:

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view
        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
END
```

Note: This method may not work with all setting changes made to Finder, although it works for `_FXSortFoldersFirst`, nonetheless `killall Finder` may be required for some settings. It's just to early to tell with macOS 10.12.

Comment: Just in case it is not obvious:
`defaults read com.apple.finder` will output all the possible settings (130 kB in my case). If you pipe it the output of the command to a file, you have created a nice reference for all options in Finder.

Comment: @mictter, I first worked with computers back in the punch card days and I'm well aware that terminal command output can be redirected to a file however, that really has nothing to do with the question or answer!

Comment: I wrote it in case someone that came across your perfectly good answer was not aware of it. Isn't precisely that the purpose of this site?

Comment: @mictter I seem to be running into problems with the command in macOS Mojave. `defaults read com.apple.finder _FXSortFoldersFirst` return `The domain/default pair of (com.apple.finder, _FXSortFoldersFirst) does not exist` in prior versions it wasn't a problem and gave a reading. Now, in Mojave, I can't seem to read any of those properties in the Advanced Finder Preferences anymore. Surely they are recorded somewhere, but don't seem to be listed in the `com.apple.finder` anymore? Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

The user .plist file does not contain every possible option by default: it only contains those values that the user has modified. It is in a binary format, but apps like BBEdit will open it and convert to text on-the-fly.

You can try changing the preferences in the UI, and seeing what values get written to the file, and making a note of them.

Apart from that, most plist keys are found by searching through the Finder's (or other app's) binary code, looking for strings that might be relevant.

Lots of useful ones have already been discovered, and there are numerous sites dedicated to listing them.